# how to login to a website by choosing from facebook / google / twitter logins

Tags: authentication, social-networking

I want mywebsite to have a login system like in this site. I will list google / facebook / twitter and openid and the user will select the provider and then login using those credentials.

Is this possible or is there already any code / plugin for this.

please suggest me

Regards,

saravanan

Comment: There are libraries to support this, but we need to know what language your webapp is in.

Answer (score 0):

its totally possible since StackOverflow offers it and many others do too.

Since you didn´t told us what technology you are using I think its not very easy to point to a specific implementation direction. However you can take a look at the docs located inside OpenId website about how to add it to your own site: http://openid.net/add-openid/

Comment: Hi tucaz,thanks for your reply. I am using php. I have used the simple class from phpclasses.org. some problem is there. Please tell me the procedure so that i can code without referring to libraries.

Comment: hope someone could answer my question

Comment: Did you check the URL in my answer? Besides all the concepts it has an extensive list of libraries to implement OpenId in each language you can think of: http://openid.net/developers/libraries/